# SharePoint 2013 List corruption Bulk Update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, bulk

I'm getting lots of complaint from end users saying that SharePoint list performs a bulk update with hundreds of records without touching/editing or even accessing the list.

I have checked if any related item connected, or even MS Excel / Projects but it seems that list somehow keeps updating.

No internal or custom workflow added.

only I noticed that in Indexed Columns there is GUID column added and I don't know what is the use of it.

Comment: You mention "any related item connected" - so is there *anything at all* connected to the list? Which values of the list (items) are updated - e.g. "Modified", "Modified By", ...? Despite the initial "nothing around it seems to connect to the list", it more than often isn't so in cases like this. Event receivers, workflows, synchronizations/connections etc. should each be gone through. It might be really hard to pinpoint you to the exact problem, so there's unfortunately a lot of responsibility and to-be-done on your end.

Comment: No Event receivers, workflows, synchronizations/connections connected to the list, only related item which I doubt that it is related to the issue.

Comment: only as you mentioned ("Modified", "Modified By") they got updated.